# convert string to date type python

Tags: python, string, date, datetime

How do I convert a string to a date object in python?

The string would be: "30-01-12" (corresponding to the format: "%d-%m-%y")

I don't want a datetime.datetime object, but rather a datetime.date

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You still use `datetime.datetime` but then request just the `.date()` portion:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('30-01-12', '%d-%m-%y').date()
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('30-01-12', '%d-%m-%y').date()
datetime.date(2012, 1, 30)
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
import datetime
s = "30-01-12"
slist = s.split("-")
sdate = datetime.date(int(slist[2]),int(slist[0]),int(slist[1]))
```

Comment: python has built in methods that handles doing this

Comment: Oops, forgot about str to int. I don't frequently use datetime, so I'm glad that there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

```
from datetime import datetime,date
date_str = '30-01-12'
formatter_string = "%d-%m-%y" 
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_str, formatter_string)
date_object = datetime_object.date()
```