# Subtracting dates and print to CSV, with Python or R

Tags: r, python-2.7, date, csv, time

I have a CSV with many rows and columns. Column D is for date of download, e.g. May 1 2014, and Column E is for date of publication, e.g. Jan 3 2014.

How can I first open and read all the dates in my CSV, then subtract the date in Column E from Column D, and write the number of days in a new column, say Column F, in a new or the same CSV?

Desired output:

```
May 1 2014    Jan 3 2014    90 (or whatever the number of days is)
```

I've done a search and I've learned [how to convert the strings to dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557828/convert-string-to-date-type-python), but I don't know how to subtract the data and print the result to a separate column.

Anyone who can help?

Comment: `as.Date("May 1 2014", format="%b %d %Y") - as.Date("Jan 3 2014", format="%b %d %Y")` gives `Time difference of 118 days` when printed and the value is `## [1] 118` numerically

Answer (score 3):

hrbrmstr's comment showed up as I was writing effectively the same answer in long form.

```
DFrame <- data.frame(date_download = "May 1 2014",
                     date_publish = "Jan 3 2014",
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

DFrame$date_download <- as.POSIXct(DFrame$date_download,
                                   format = "%b %d %Y")
DFrame$date_publish <- as.POSIXct(DFrame$date_publish,
                                  format = "%b %d %Y")

DFrame$diff <- difftime(DFrame$date_download, 
                        DFrame$date_publish, 
                        units="days")

DFrame

write.csv(DFrame, [filename], ...)
```

You can either use the `-` operator, or the `difftime` function to get the same result.

See `?write.csv` for additional options to control what is written to your file.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm looking for, but how do I write this to a column in the same or in a new CSV?

Comment: You'll have to do it with a new csv using `write.csv`.

Comment: Is there any chance you can include this in the code you pasted above? I don't know how to use write.csv in R. :/

Comment: `write.csv` is fairly straight forward.  I added the basics, but I'll encourage you to read the documentation to work out exactly how you want to file to be written.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Could you have a look at the updated question, I clarified that I also need to open and read the dates from a CSV.

Comment: Interestingly enough, `as.Date` is _significantly_ more efficient than `as.POSIXct` (tho that prbly isn't a need of the OP) _but_ the `difftime` for `POSIXct` objects is marginally faster than for `Date` objects.

Comment: so you're saying my decision process on whether to use `Date` or `POSIX` classes should be dictated by more than just "POSIX is cool?"

Answer (score 1):

THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER but a follow-up from my comment on benchmarking, since this may be a consideration in a larger-scale data situation.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

autoplot(microbenchmark(as_date=as.Date("May 1 2014", format="%b %d %Y"),
                        as_posixct=as.POSIXct("May 1 2014", format="%b %d %Y"), 
                        as_posixlt=strptime("May 1 2014", format="%b %d %Y"), 
                        times=100000))
```

[image]

```
d1_d <- as.Date("May 1 2014", format="%b %d %Y")
d2_d <- as.Date("Jan 3 2014", format="%b %d %Y")

d1_p1 <- as.POSIXct("May 1 2014", format="%b %d %Y")
d2_p1 <- as.POSIXct("Jan 3 2014", format="%b %d %Y")

d1_p2 <- strptime("May 1 2014", format="%b %d %Y")
d2_p2 <- strptime("Jan 3 2014", format="%b %d %Y")

autoplot(microbenchmark(date_difftime=difftime(d2_d, d1_d),
                        date_subtract=d2_d-d1_d,
                        posixct_difftime=difftime(d2_p1, d1_p1), 
                        posixct_subtract=d2_p1-d1_p1,
                        posixlt_difftime=difftime(d2_p2, d1_p2), 
                        posixlt_subtract=d2_p2-d1_p2,
                        times=10000))
```

[image]

It would seem `Date` objects may be an overall best choice (if working strictly with dates and not timestamps) and `difftime` wins against simple subtraction.